# PyQt combo box change value of a label

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5 to make a UI to a project.

I want to change the value of a label when the user changes the value of a combo box.

Can anyone help me to find out wich method to use to 'trigger' the function that changes the value of the label ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you mean the signal of combo box, when it's value changed, you can use

```
QComboBox.currentTextChanged
```

or

```
QComboBox.currentIndexChanged
```

Everytime a combobox is changed by user, these signals will be triggered.

Suppose `cb_1` is your combobox
a simple function in you parent/widget class like

```
def on_combobox_changed(self, value):
    print("combobox changed", value)
    # do your code
```

just

```
cb_1.currentTextChanged.connect(self.on_combobox_changed)
```

try to change the combobox and see what will happen

Comment: Thank you very much ! It worked. I just had to add a to the signal. It ended like : self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_combobox_changed, self.comboBox.currentIndex())